What does "recommended" mean for a subject GRE?
There are a few institutions in the US that seem to "recommend" the subject GRE but do not make it mandatory. For instance, the Cornell Physics Department says:

The general GRE and the physics GRE will not be considered for applicants with interests in experimental physics or physics education research. The physics GRE is recommended for applicants with interests in research in either theoretical elementary particle physics or theoretical condensed matter physics.

What does this mean for a student interested in pursuing theoretical particle physics/condensed matter physics (assuming they have a standard amount of research experience, strong recommendations from their supervisors and a high CGPA at the end of their undergraduate program)? Is submitting the GRE scores mandatory or does it mean that while optional, the application will be negatively affected if scores are not submitted? Additionally, should such a candidate explain (in their statements) the reason they did not attach the GRE scores?
While I do say "undergraduate", I will actually finish my Master's next year and am looking to join a graduate program in the fall of next year. This means that I have taken (and performed well on) advanced physics courses as part of my Master's program. The Physics GRE would involve considerable finances for me and time - on top of that, the exam is not conducted anywhere close to my place of residence and would involve considerable travelling (and the associated costs of accommodation) as well. Most places in the US I am looking into do not require the GRE, so I would like to skip it completely - however, if it indeed boosts my chances of selection significantly, I am willing to consider appearing for the examination.

I'm pretty sure I've seen this discussed several times in Academia SE -- see the "Related" questions listed at the right side of your question, and look at (at least their titles) the questions (linked & related) for each of those. My feeling, however, is that if you think you would be a strong candidate for the graduate programs you are most interested in, then do not take the exam. Probably only take the exam if you feel you have some shortcomings (grades, letters of recommendations, out-of-class activities, etc.) AND you are fairly confident that you can obtain a relatively strong score.

By the way, my previous comment is based on the fact that you said taking the exam would be a hardship for you. It's possible you could mention this hardship (hence why did not take the exam) in your application letter (if it exists; I'm not talking about your research plans letter, or statement of purpose letter, or whatever), but I'm not sure if this would do more harm than good -- others here are in a better position than I am to judge this.

@DaveLRenfro Thanks for the response. I did look into the related questions before I posted this on the site. I think they are similar but not the same - specifically, none of them relate to the Physics GRE and there isn't a question of how a candidate should interpret "recommended" (there is one for "optional").

Consider also that submitting good GRE scores would be taken as a positive for you (in contrast to how you phrased things). They only have so much information to use to select students. More information is usually better particularly for you if you have a good score. But there are plenty of other places that do not require it.
